# meteor publish/subscribe confusion

Tags: javascript, meteor

So, in my *server.js* I have the following code to limit what the client receives:

```
Meteor.publish('customerList', function()
{
    return Meteor.users.find({roles: 'customer'}, {fields: {profile: 1}});
});
```

I only want to find users with 'roles' of value 'customer', using the Roles package. Then on the *client.js* I do ANOTHER `find()` in a subscribe:

```
Meteor.subscribe('customerList', function()
{
    var foundCustomers = Meteor.users.find().fetch();

    Session.set('foundCustomers', foundCustomers); //i have a Session.get elsewhere which returns this cursor
});
```

And ofcourse in my template I show these values like this:

```
<template name="customer_search_result">
    {{#each customers}}
        <div>{{profile.firstname}} {{profile.lastname}}, {{profile.tel}}</div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

So what am I doing wrong when I am seeing all of the different roles in this list now? If I add the same rules in my subscribed `find()` as in my published then we get no result at all.

Comment: You have removed the autopublish package?

Comment: Yepp, that is right, I removed the autopublish package because it was something that Roles complained about ^^

Comment: That publish is the only publish that publishes documents from the `Meteor.users` collection?

Comment: What does the `roles` field contain for a user you want to exclude? Is it just e.g. `['admin']` or is it something like `['admin', 'customer']`? (You can check by typing `meteor mongo` at the command line and then doing `db.users.find()`)

Comment: No Peppe, there is one other that publishes the "employee" type of users. I want to publish both an employeeList and a customerList. user3374348, roles only contain one string like "admin" or "customer" atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is another publication which publishes the `employee`s, you'll need to take just the `customer`s from `Meteor.users` in the subscribe callback, otherwise you might get some `employee`s as well. First, add `roles` to the published fields (I assume this isn't a problem):

```
Meteor.publish('customerList', function()
{
    return Meteor.users.find({roles: 'customer'}, {fields: {profile: 1, roles: 1}});
});
```

Then update the subscribe function:

```
Meteor.subscribe('customerList', function()
{
    var foundCustomers = Meteor.users.find({roles: 'customer'}).fetch();
    Session.set('foundCustomers', foundCustomers);
});
```

By the way, by `fetch`ing the cursor and storing the results in the session, you will break reactivity. If this is intentional - you just want a once-off snapshot of the customers - you should consider stopping the subscription after you're done with it, otherwise the server will keep sending new customers to the client which are never used:

```
var customerListSubscription = Meteor.subscribe('customerList', function()
{
    var foundCustomers = Meteor.users.find({roles: 'customer'}).fetch();
    Session.set('foundCustomers', foundCustomers);
    customerListSubscription.stop();
});
```

If you want reactivity, see Kelly Copley's answer.

Comment: when I log this it returns just "[ ]", nothing

Comment: Oh, you'll have to include `roles` in the published fields as well (`{fields: {profile: 1, roles: 1}}`). Right now, you don't publish it, so the client can't use it to `find` by.

Answer (score 1):

Your publish and template look fine, you just need to change your subscribe like this:

```
Meteor.subscribe('customerList');
```

Then you need a template helper like so:

```
Template.customer_search_result.helpers({
    customers: function(){
        return Meteor.users.find({roles: 'customer'}, {fields: {profile: 1}});
    }
})
```